# ipazzport mouse issue

Tags: mouse

I've recently upgraded my pi3 OS using

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Before I upgraded my ipazzport keyboard and mouse pad were working fine.  Post upgrade my ipazzport mouse has changed axis, so inorder to move the cursor up the screen I have to swipe to the left.  This isn't ideal.  Is there a way to change this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, this is a keyboard config that's done on the keyboard itself rather than in code.  To change the keyboard aspect click Fn and Esc at the same time. Problem solved.